# Print out pandas groupby without operation

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

So I have the following pandas dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
sample_df = pd.DataFrame({'note': ['D','C','D','C'], 'time': [1,1,4,6], 'val': [6,4,7,9]})
```

which gives the result

```
    note  time  val
0   D     1     6
1   C     1     4
2   D     4     7
3   C     6     9
```

What I want is

```
note  index   time  val
C     1        1    4
      3        6    9
D     0        1    6
      2        4    7
```

I tried `sample_df.set_index('note',append=True)` and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`DataFrame.swaplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) with [`DataFrame.sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) by first level:

```
df = sample_df.set_index('note', append=True).swaplevel(1,0).sort_index(level=0)
print (df)
        time  val
note             
C    1     1    4
     3     6    9
D    0     1    6
     2     4    7
```

If need set level name add [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = (sample_df.rename_axis('idx')
               .set_index('note',append=True)
               .swaplevel(1,0)
               .sort_index(level=0))
print (df)
          time  val
note idx           
C    1       1    4
     3       6    9
D    0       1    6
     2       4    7
```

Alternatively:

```
sample_df.index.rename('old_index', inplace=True) 
sample_df.reset_index(inplace=True)
sample_df.set_index(['note','old_index'], inplace=True)
sample_df.sort_index(level=0, inplace=True)
print (sample_df)
                time  val
note old_index           
C    1             1    4
     3             6    9
D    0             1    6
     2             4    7
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked fine. Have a question though. I tried doing `sample_df.index.rename('old_index', inplace=True`, `sample_df.reset_index(inplace=True)`, `sample_df.set_index(['note','old_index'], inplace=True)`, `sample_index.sort_index(level=0)` but I don't get the same results as yours. What's the reason?

Comment: @irene this last line `sample_index.sort_index(level=0, inplace=True)` :-)

Comment: @irene - For last use `sample_df.sort_index(level=0, inplace=True)`

Answer (score 1):

I am using `MultiIndex` create the target index

```
sample_df.index=pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([sample_df.note,sample_df.index])
sample_df.drop('note',1,inplace=True)
sample_df=sample_df.sort_index(level=0)
sample_df
        time  val
note             
C    1     1    4
     3     6    9
D    0     1    6
     2     4    7
```

Comment: Simple and intuitive, thanks! Would you know how this compares to @jezrael's method in terms of memory and speed?

Comment: @irene I am not , would you like test in your end by the real data ? :-)

Comment: Honestly, I've never tried that before haha. I'll study how to use `timeit` first :)

Answer (score 0):

I would use `set_index` and `pop` to simultaneously discard column 'note' and set new index

```
df.set_index([df.pop('note'), df.index]).sort_index(level=0)

Out[380]:
        time  val
note
C    1     1    4
     3     6    9
D    0     1    6
     2     4    7
```

Comment: I'm not sure why this gives a different result from intended. It seems the `df.pop` procedure causes the (row) ordering of the rest of the columns to be messed up. Without the `df.pop`, this works just as well as the others.

Comment: @irene: It's weird! I am puzzled. I tried on your sample and the result is correct as shown. I made a few longer samples on rows and columns and tried on both python 3.4/pandas 0.21 and python 3.7/pandas 0.24.2. I could not reproduce the messing up columns order after `pop`.

Comment: In my full dataset, the notes are categorical variables and are sorted by pitch (so that goes from A0 to maybe B6). Could that be the reason? It's just the `pop` that's problematic.